# Plugin to show stackoverflow answer preview in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Paarts of my code have snippets taken from stackoverflow answers.

Currently I'm including the link in a comment above the method, but I was told that there might be a plugin to show a preview of the answer.

Does anyone know if this exists?

Comment: Why do you need to include the link for every piece of code inspired by S.O.? If I had done the same, my code would be looking *very* cluttered by now.

Comment: We're creating a webdriver suite of tests, sometimes there's issues with finding ajax elements that we have solved by referencing bugfixes here.

Adding the url to the comments helps us understaand the reasoning behind the fixes, rather than trying to remember after 3/4 months why something was done.

Comment: I would be more tempted to add the links to the checkin comments (or the README.md) instead, and leave a concise short comment in the actual code.